# Unable to get Value from hidden Input type using Python

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to get the value from a hidden input field in a form. The page has 4 forms, and each form has a different value for the hidden input field - each for a different quarter of the year.

```
        <form method="get" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{1}}">
            <button class="btn btn-med btn-primary shadow-sm quarter-button">1st Quarter</button>
        </form>
        <form method="get" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{2}}">
            <button class="btn btn-med btn-primary shadow-sm quarter-button">2nd Quarter</button>
        </form>
        <form method="get" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{3}}">
            <button class="btn btn-med btn-primary shadow-sm quarter-button">3rd Quarter</button>
        </form>
        <form method="get" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{4}}">
            <button class="btn btn-med btn-primary shadow-sm quarter-button">4th Quarter</button>
        </form>
```

The python looks like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    sales_data = Sales.query.all()
    if request.method == "GET":
        quarter = request.form.get("name")
        print(quarter)
    return render_template("index.html", sales_data=sales_data)
```

When the button of each form is pressed, I want the value from the hidden input field to be passed to the quarter variable. Am I going about this all wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: When clicking the buttons to submit the forms, the values in the input tags get added to the url as the following: ?value=1

Comment: Why are you interpolating the integer values? I recommend you try `value=“4”` instead of the `value=“{{4}}”` the second one asks for the string value of the variable `4`. I would wager you don’t have a variable by that name and the reason for the `None`

Comment: I removed the brackets around the values to no avail. I'm not quite sure what you mean about the variable 4 part, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You haved assigned `value` as `name` to your `input`s therefore you should do

```
quarter = request.form.get("value")
```

Comment: I tried this and sadly got the same result as above. The variable gets assigned None.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I followed Daweo's answer and

1. Changed the `request.form.get("name")` to `request.form.get("value")`
2. Removed brackets around the values as Jarvis suggested,
3. Changed the method of the form to be `POST`, not `GET`
4. Applied this change to the python code

which fixed the issue

Comment: Glad you solved with the pieces we each offered!